# What is the maximum size of a Post to Urban Airships "Batch Push"?

Tags: rest, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

So [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) supports the concept of "Batch Push"

https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/APIs%253A+Push+iOS

What is the maximum amount of data that can be sent via this method?

Comment: Are you referring to the payload of the notification?

Comment: @EmilePetrone no. I am wondering if there is any limit to the amount of data I can push through a request.

Comment: did you ever find out? I'm going through the same problem right now. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

While I wasn't able to find any official documentation on a hard limit, this page seems to indicate a recommended maximum of 1000 pushes per batched call:

https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1069013-helpful-curl-examples

(scroll down to the example titled "***Sending a batch of several pushes in one request***")